# Making Iphone App in Dreamweaver, javascript force reload of page causes loss of back button

Tags: javascript, dreamweaver

I am using Adobe Dreamweaver CS5.5 to make some photography related iPhone apps.

One is a Photography Assignment app that will allow people to go through a list of various assignments they can try out to improve their photography

I have one that is supposed to provide a random object and environment for the student.

I have it so the javascript that provides the random object/environment works.
However, I would like to have it so they can hit a button to get a new set.

I tried adding these codes:

which works, but when it does so, I lose the BACK button at the top, therefore they will be stuck on that page.

Any thoughts?

Noel

Comment: on further research, this appears to be the problem: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/933
but i dont know how to program the BACK button link to go to "#page" which is the main page of the app.